# what to use instead of tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence in tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: tensorflow

i have no idea of what to use instead of tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence. i am using tensorflow 2.1.0.

i have tried this 
tf.keras.layers.Embedding but showing error==>ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: 15

Comment: I think you should paste your code. So that it will be easy to answer question. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the reply I am using this code https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/seq2seq/sequence_to_sequence_implementation.ipynb